# How can I find a similar circuit design like the one in Chargetech or Omnicharge( DC to AC 85 Watt )?

Tags: ac, dc, power-electronics, inverter

I would like to build one 85 Watt DC to AC Inverter for my personal use.

After seeing the designs of Omnicharge and Chargetech I wonder whether the Circuit and component descriptions are available to build the same.

Can someone guide me to build a small signature DC to AC Inverter?

1. Small Circuit with less heat dissipation
2. 12v 20000mah DC  to 85Watt 230v AC.

Any kind of pointers or guidance in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a free design service. Show your efforts.

Comment: G O O G L E   I T !

Comment: It is better  you read than ask for personal trainer. perhaps ask better questions next time with more focus and experience